# 'jsireact/JSIExecutor.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I am working on react native application without Expo. I am trying to use react-native-video package. Also I am running project in Xcode with **cocoapods**.

Here is my pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'


target 'myprj' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
 # Pods for myprj
  # Your 'node_modules' directory is probably in the root of your project,
  # but if not, adjust the `:path` accordingly

 pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
 'Core',
 'CxxBridge',
 'DevSupport'
 ]
 # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
 pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

 # Third party deps podspec link
 pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
 pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
 pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

 pod 'react-native-video', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-video'


  target 'myprj-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing

    pod 'react-native-video', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-video'

  end

  target 'myprjTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Now when I am trying to run project its giving below error:

**node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm:37:9: fatal error: 'jsireact/JSIExecutor.h' file not found**

Please suggest me for solution of it, as I tried to search but didn't find any solution.

Please check this screenshot as well.

[image]

Please find my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myprj",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "immutability-helper": "^3.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.3",
    "react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-video": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
    "jest": "24.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add package.json ?

Comment: @NazırDogan added

Comment: I think this is react-native bug. They are making big changes with core. as far I know jsi is new thing. and its have some bug. I suggest create project with 0.57

Comment: Search jsi term in page. https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/4

Comment: Hello, i think it is a bug with `use_frameworks!` and jsi if you remove it you will be able to build again.

Answer (score 9):

**Update**: This has been resolved in `react-native: "0.58.5"` and greater.

---

The issue is with `HEADER SEARCH PATHS` in the React Native subspec for `jsiexecutor` on the `master` branch of `"react-native": "0.58.3"`

Source:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/23274/files

Temporary fix:

1. Open `React.podspec` found in `node_modules/react-native/React.podspec`
2. Update `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` of `jsiexecutor` subspec to read:

```
  s.subspec "jsiexecutor" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/cxxreact"
    ss.dependency             "React/jsi"
    ss.dependency             "Folly", folly_version
    ss.compiler_flags       = folly_compiler_flags
    ss.source_files         = "ReactCommon/jsiexecutor/jsireact/*.{cpp,h}"
    ss.private_header_files = "ReactCommon/jsiexecutor/jsireact/*.h"
    ss.header_dir           = "jsireact"
    ss.pod_target_xcconfig  = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "\"$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/ReactCommon\", \"$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor\"" }
  end
```

3. Run `pod update`

Comment: It appears that React Native release version `0.58.4` from today does not yet include the fix for this issue.

Comment: I have removed POD from project. Thanks all for your reply :)

Answer (score 3):

This is now been fixed in `react-native 0.58.5`, which now should be working without manually patching the `podspec` file.
[React native release notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.58.5)